# General about website after logged in with MySql db

Tags: php, mysql, css

So my question is alittle confusing. Like Facebook, you have main-page. 
After you log in the url stays the same but instead of seeing the login/register page you'll see your news feed etc.

I use PHP on my webpage, after i login i'll get the echo msg "**You've logged in!**"
Is it possible me to redirect back to the main-page with new layout on the website, but the URL could stay the same?

```
<?php>
require('nameofit.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$Username = mysql_escape_string($_POST['Username']);
$pass = mysql_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
$pass = md5($pass);

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Username` = '$Username' AND `pass` = '$pass'");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
    echo "You're logged in.";
    exit();
}else{
    echo "Wrong Username or Password, make sure you entered the right information.";

}

}else{


$form = <<<EOT
<form action="login.php" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="Username" /><br />
Password: <input type="password" name="pass" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
EOT;
echo $form;
}

?>
```

Comment: Yes that is possible.

Comment: You need be more specific in your question, please EDIT. For example: you use what? A framework? Pure PHP? You can post a example of your code and login function?

Comment: When you're talking about magically updating pages without leaving the page you're on, you're talking about AJAX, and usually jQuery or another AJAX library. Go forth and google!

Comment: it doesn't have to be ajax, just the same page with conditions on what to show depending on variables xD

Comment: You should change the '<?php>' to '<?php' in your sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your login operation is a `POST`, you can do that with `header`

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Using that you will redirect to **previous page**.

Or you can set whatever you want:

```
header('Location: index.php');
header('Location: /index.php');
header('Location: http://www.yoursite.com');
header('Location: directory/whatever/page.php');
```

## Solution

```
if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
} else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password, make sure you entered the right information.";
}
```

## Important

Don't do that.

Don't execute `SELECT` or whatever in database in your view.

Follow the [good pratices](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/30-php-best-practices-for-beginners/), [always update your knowledge](https://tutsplus.com/2013/03/the-modern-php-developer/), use a [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php), etc.

Comment: I think you need an absolute URL in a Location header or many browsers will fail.

Comment: Sincerely I don't know, I'll check now.

Comment: @user2654319 Your problem was solved with my answer?

Comment: It confuses me actually ;)

Comment: @user2654319 How? You not understand the use of `header` or you can't implement that? (I update my answer... see above.. try using my code, and let me know if works)

Comment: I think your solution needs a bit to moch knownledge on classes and PHP coding for him to be adapted quickly. A more basic approach might work.

Comment: Thank you Patrick, i understanded the code mostly (not in the best relationship with it) i didn't understand the 'Location', like can it really send the info that way, but it worked so yeah thanks again.

Comment: @user2654319 You can send this way: `header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . '?login=success);` or whatever you want. Like a GET parameter... and check that in your view.

Answer (score 0):

after successful login, store information about user being logged in in session, and just refresh the page.
On the main page, first check if any info about user exists in session. If not - display login page, if yes - display regular content, news or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php

    $logincookie = $_COOKIE['login'];

    if($logincookie == 'value'){
      //MAIN PAGE
    }else{
      //LOGIN PAGE
    } ?>
```

Comment: Please do NOT use a cookie for your login state as it can be easily exploted. Use a $_SESSION instead.